# How to compute total interference power at receiver antenna

Tags: signal-power, interference

I would like to know what is the proper way to sum interferences.
I have, for example, let say  0.4 mW, 0.035 mW and 0.2 mW are those interferences.

Do I have to sum them resulting 0.635 mW or make a conversion to log scale, for example, dBm and add these dBm log values?

The results are different; if I convert the three interferences 0.4 mW, 0.035 mW, and 0.2 mW to dBm and then sum them, it results in -25.52 dBm, which back to linear scale is 2.8$\mu$ W

Comment: It would help if you explain what you’re trying to do with all this, it is not clear to me from the question. For example, are you trying to get a per antenna metric or doing some processing to obtain a single signal?

Comment: @Engineer Thank you. I want to add the total interference to the noise level and get the SNIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to sum the interference is to sum them in power, unless they are coherent, in which case they would sum in magnitude. Coherent would mean the interference are all at the same frequency and locked in phase. This is unlikely so if not state explicitly you would assume the are non-coherent and a power sum should be used.

To sum them in power you would simply add the powers and then convert the sum to dBm. If starting from dBm, you would convert them to power quantity first, add and then convert back to dBm as demonstrated below using the OP's quantities:

0.4 mW is -3.98 dBm

0.035 mW is -14.56 dBm

0.2 mW is -6.99 dBm

The total power would be 0.4 + 0.035 + 0.2 mW = 0.635 mW which is $10\log_{10}(0.635)= -1.97$ dBm.

If we started with the dBm quantities we could compute this same result as follows:

$$10\log(10^{-3.98/10}+10^{-14.56/1}+10^{-6.99/10})$$